# Is there any way to create new publishing options for articles?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm looking to add a new publishing option inside my articles, so if I want to associate an SVG with the article we can add specific code if a parameter is yes or exclude if the same parameter is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to perform two actions.

First you should add a new extra field for your articles. I recommend to use this extension

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/aixeena-cck

It allows you to create new fields for articles using Joomla plugins, so the solutions is really clean.

Once you have added a field to indicate the svg file you have to override the com_content article view.

There is plenty information on the internet about how to do that, like:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager/es#Creating_Overrides

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Absolutely amazing plugin; Already utilising the overrides, so I'm familiar with that.

Comment: Great you like it!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Zoo component from yootheme.com

This component have any possibilities to create custom fields. 
You can customize this fields in front-end with various div class.

Its great possibilitie custization In front-end.

I hope this help.