# Adding a note to an article

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, articles, article-manager

I often would like to add a note to my articles (eg. this article must be unpublished because of that). The note will only help backend users.

A (too short*) field has already been implemented for categories and menus. But strangely not for articles, yet.

The ideal would be to be able to read the note directly from the article manager (without having to open it) **just like it does for the category/menu note field which is displayed next to the alias**.

I'm surprise to don't find the note field in article. I did not find any extension that would allow to add a note. did I miss something? (I don't use any component to edit my article)

ps: adding a "version note" won't work since it will disappear once the article will be saved (that's the point of a version note!).

(* the field size, and characters lengths are too short, in my opinion).

Comment: I added an issue to the Joomla tracker about this: https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/16180

Answer (score 1):

You are really right. A note field for articles can come very handy.

In the meanwhile I suggest you to add your own field for notes in articles using this plugin:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/authoring-a-content/content-construction/aixeena-cck

I also suggest you check this:

[Is there any way to create new publishing options for articles?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13975/is-there-any-way-to-create-new-publishing-options-for-articles/13976#13976)

Hope it works for you

Comment: Bump. No news about this? There is a field called "version note", but I can't find the corresponding database column.